# Feature Set from Mosaic Dataset Using Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, mosaic-dataset, image-service

Testing an arcpy script that uses [Manage Tile Cache](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/manage-tile-cache.htm). One of the parameters is "Area of Interest" which takes a Feature Set datatype. In GIS I can select on the mosaic dataset, then use the footprint as input for that parameter and the tool works.

So programmatically I tried a similar approach but the selection fails. How can I capture the feature set of a mosaic dataset selection?

EDIT - Also tried to make a feature layer w/ the query instead of select by attributes.

```py
import arcpy, os

# change workspace to Imagery gdb
md_name = os.path.basename(input_md) # `input_md` is a valid mosaic dataset w/ rasters
base_gdb = os.path.dirname(input_md)
arcpy.env.workspace = base_gdb

# query footprint Area of Interest
aoi_query = "Category = 1 And Name = 'DrakesCornerSP-2019-08-08_COG'"

# NOTE: Issue here. How to obtain Feature Set for `area_of_interest` param? 
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(r"{}\Footprint".format(md_name), "NEW_SELECTION", aoi_query, None) # fail
# arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(md_name, "NEW_SELECTION", input_aoi_query, None) # fail
# arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(input_md, "NEW_SELECTION", input_aoi_query, None) # fail

# get scales list from cache .xml 
lst_scales = read_cache_xml(input_service_cache) 

base_folder = os.path.dirname(input_service_cache)
mode = "RECREATE_ALL_TILES"
cacheName = os.path.basename(input_service_cache)
useScheme = "ARCGISONLINE_SCHEME"

# update service cache
with arcpy.EnvManager(parallelProcessingFactor="100"):
    arcpy.AddMessage(f'\n\tRebuilding cache tiles for image service:\n\t{cacheName}')
    arcpy.ManageTileCache_management(in_cache_location = base_folder, 
        manage_mode = mode,
        in_cache_name = cacheName, 
        in_datasource = input_md, 
        tiling_scheme = useScheme,
        scales = lst_scales , 
        area_of_interest = f"{input_md}\Footprint"
        min_cached_scale = max(lst_scales), 
        max_cached_scale= min(lst_scales))
```

Comment: Can you confirm, when you say "in GIS...it works", and in the script you have a # fails -- does this mean when you run the script inside ArcGIS Pro/ArcMap, it WORKS, but when you run the script outside the application, it fails?

Comment: Correct. I can successfully perform all the steps - Select By Attributes on Mosaic Dataset + run Manage Tile Cache in GIS. Same operation fails in the script.

Comment: To clarify further - I can perform all of the steps MANUALLY. The script snippet is part of a custom GP tool, also being executed in GIS - which fails.